# Run multiples detectMultiScale() on parallel

Tags: opencv, openmp, object-detection, tbb

I'm working on a mobile application that detects closed and opened eyes. For now it is running sequentially, since I'm a novice on parallelization, but I want the two 'detectMultiScale' methods to be running on multiple cores, because frame per second number needs to be increased. The raw detectMultiScale code is shown below:

```
eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceTrackedROI, eyes, 1.1, 5, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(10,5));
eyesclosed_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceTrackedROI, eyesclosed, 1.25, 6, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(10, 5), Size(50,25) );
```

I have done a lot of researches, which have led me to TBB and OpenMP. Which one is recommended for this application? How can I use it to parallel these methods?

Comment: I'd say keep it simple -- you'll most likely do fine just firing off those functions on `std::thread` or with `std::async`.

Comment: For an embedded environment in which your program does not own the machine (other operations are "stealing" CPU cores away from you)m the TBB parallelism model is generally better than that of "classic" OpenMP.